# Как сделать вертикальный слайдер в несколько колонок?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swiper, carousel

Нужен адаптивный вертикальный слайдер, который бы выводил слайды в несколько колонок.
Перепробовал owl, bxslider, swiper. Не могу нагуглить никакого решения.
На float, grid, flex без разницы.

К примеру вот тут курс криптовалют в строку и он сменяется вертикально https://www.binance.com/en

Первый слайд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй слайд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А на планшетах и мобильных, чтобы кол-во колонок уменьшалось.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2g63xcbm/ вот к примеру, вертикальный слайдер 2 слайда друг под другом. Как сделать чтобы эти 2 слайда были в ряд?

Comment: Так в чем проблема со свайпером (с owl понятно, он три года как закрыт и переехал на tiny-slider) покажите код, что у вас получилось. Создайте [mre] и все получится.

Comment: В принципе не понятно зачем для смены двух слайдов какая-то библиотека или плагин

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) с режимом vertical

Уменьшать кол-во можно тем, что через `@media` скрывать часто блоков `.oneslider`

Пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-class').slick({
    infinite: true,
    vertical: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  });
});
```

```css
.vertical-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.oneslider {
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css">

<div class="vertical-flex">
  <div class="oneslider">
    <div class="your-class">
      <div>your content</div>
      <div>your content</div>
      <div>your content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="oneslider">
    <div class="your-class">
      <div>your content</div>
      <div>your content</div>
      <div>your content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="oneslider">
    <div class="your-class">
      <div>your content</div>
      <div>your content</div>
      <div>your content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="oneslider">
    <div class="your-class">
      <div>your content</div>
      <div>your content</div>
      <div>your content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```